# Zoom reset in Firefox not resetting properly

Tags: html, firefox

Is Zoom reset in Firefox 22 broken? When I measure HTML elements with a ruler, everything is wider than what they are supposed to be. Firebug's Layout displays the proper width. When I zoom reset, it doesn't reset to the proper zoom level. I have to zoom out a couple of times more.

Why does the zoom reset behave this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Windows, Firefox 22 introduces a support for the pixel density you've set on a system level in the windows control panel > appearance > display.

You can still go on con firefo config by typing `about:config` into the firefox address bar, and look for `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`. double-click to change its value to `1.0`.

Reference: http://support.mozilla.org/it/questions/963759#answer-451851

Comment: That worked. Although all the text including the menus became too small for me. I think I will just remember to have to ctrl+0, ctrl+-. ctrl+- when I measure stuff. Thanks.